# Getting all data from line before and after the matched pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search a log file for a pattern using preg_match_all
however the regex doesn't seem to be working quite right.
It saying no matches

Here is a sample line from the log file

```
04:19:58 | Player "xxx" (id=xxx pos=<3748.4, 5976.5, 403.3>)
```

I am trying to search for the pos=< > and store the values in an array but I also need the other content on the line

```
  $contents = file_get_contents('logs/'.$log);

  $pattern = '/pos=<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)>/m';

 // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
 if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
 echo "Found matches:\n";
 echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
 }
 else{
 echo "No matches found";
 }
```

Comment: The pattern does not match as there is no `$` character and there are no double quotes in the string. See https://regex101.com/r/IFSrwJ/1

Comment: If it is a log file `grep` with `-A` and `-B` would be easier to use, or in my opinion at least...otherwise I'd use `file` instead of `file_get_contents` then iterate over and look. You then can use matched key to get next and previous line numbers.

Comment: Is it line before and line after, or just the three values in the brackets?

Comment: updated the code .. its getting the data inside the < > but how can I get the data from before & after ?

Comment: Do you mean using another capture group? `^(.*pos=)<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)>` https://regex101.com/r/lvG7YK/1

Comment: Im now getting no ending delimited '^' found

Comment: The pattern should be between delimiters in php `/(.*pos=)<(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)>/`

Comment: Works perfect .. thank you ! I need to learn regex properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
$pattern = '/pos\=\<(.*?)\,(.*?)\,(.*?)\>/m';
```

Use regex debuggers like this one https://regex101.com

Comment: It works but how can I get the data on the line for example 04:19:58 | Player "xxx"  which is before the pos=<> and there is always data after the > thatI need to get

Comment: If the entries on the log file are uniform, use this regexp to parse them:

/((\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2}))\s\|\sPlayer\s\"(.+?)\".+?\(id=(.+?)\spos\=\<(.+?)\,\s(.+?)\,\s(.+?)\>\)/gm

I made the time parsed "twice" - entire time and hours, minutes, seconds separately.

https://regex101.com/r/4yM4ea/1

Answer (score 0):

For the example string, you can add an extra capture group before the opening  `<`

Note that you don't need the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern.

The `.*?` part can be written using a negated character class `[^,\r\n]*` to match any char except a newline or `,` to prevent the non greedy quantifier and some backtracking.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/7XvJG) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EuvSZy/1).

```
$pattern = '/(pos=)<([^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*),([^,\r\n]*)>/';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    print_r($matches);
}
else{
    echo "No matches found";
}
```

Output

```
Found matches:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => pos=<3748.4, 5976.5, 403.3>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => pos=
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3748.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  5976.5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  403.3
        )

)
```